# Add Different confirm message Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two links the edit and remove button. What I want is to separate the confirm message of edit to remove. When I clicked edit button the message is for edit button and if remove button another message shows. How I can do that?

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.button.edit, a.button.remove').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if(!confirm('Do you want to continue?')){
            return
        }

        var frm = document.myform;
        if ($(this).hasClass('edit')) {
            frm.action = 'editpr.php';
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) {}
        frm.submit();
    })
})
</script>

  <a class="button edit" style="cursor:pointer;"><span><b>Edit Purchase Request</b></span></a>
  <a class="button remove" style="cursor:pointer;" name="remove"><span><b>Remove Purchase Request</b></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, check the class and make confirm message correspondingly

```
   $('a.button.edit, a.button.remove').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if($(this).hasClass('edit')) {  
          if(!confirm('Do you want to edit?')){
            return
          }
        else {
          if(!confirm('Do you want to remove?')){
            return
          }
        }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/eXtj4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    var triggerClick = function(str) {
        $('a.button.' + str).click(function () {
            if ($('input[name="checkbox[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            if(!confirm('Do you want to continue?')){
                return;
            }
            var frm = document.myform;
            frm.action = str + '.php';
            frm.submit();
        });
    };
    triggerClick('edit');
    triggerClick('remove');
})
</script>
```